# habit of pow(a, b) function in c++ (IDE Visual Studio 2019)

Tags: c++, radix, pow, exponent

please, if somebody can explain. I have some questions about habit of pow(a, b) function in c++ (IDE Visual Studio 2019).
During exercises I found strange habit of x++ and ++x in library  function pow(a,b), precisely, I can't understand why such results:

```
int x=1;
cout << "pow(x++, x) = " << pow(x++, x) << endl;
```

all right in this case, result is:

```
pow(x++, x)=1
```

but in case of:

```
int x=1;
cout << "pow(x, x++) = " << pow(x, x++) << endl;
```

result is:

```
pow(x, x++)=2
```

why postcrement effects so differently?

additional cases:

```
int x=1;
cout << "pow(++x, ++x) = " << pow(++x, ++x) << endl;
```

result is:

```
pow(++x, ++x)=27
```

it's clear, but if:

```
int x=1;
cout << "pow(++x, x++) = " << pow(++x, x++) << endl;
```

result is:

```
pow(++x, x++)=3
```

another case:

```
int x=1;
cout << "pow(x++, ++x) = " << pow(x++, ++x) << endl;
```

result is:

```
pow(x++, ++x)=8
```

and one more:

```
int x=1;
cout << "pow(x++, x++) = " << pow(x++, x++) << endl;
```

result is:

```
pow(x++, x++)=2
```

in some variations results are as expected, but in some variations - not expected.

Comment: There should many dupes on the line of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-pre-and-post-increment-undefined-behavior and some more specific about the order of evaluation of function arguments not being determined. Also, while not the issue here,  `pow` accepts and returns floating-point values.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are these constructs using pre and post-increment undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-pre-and-post-increment-undefined-behavior)

Comment: @phuclv Things are not clearly undefined here as the reference makes it seem. I think that VS 2019 compiles in C++17 mode by default, and there the function argument evaluations are indeterminately sequenced, not unsequenced. Most, if not all of, the examples are well-defined, albeit unspecified.